# Expressjs not loading stylesheets on heroku, giving 500 error

Tags: node.js, express, stylesheet, pug, stylus

I'm running an Expressjs installation on heroku, and it's not loading the stylesheets.

I hit ctrl+u and then click on the stylesheet link, and get this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<SendStream> has no method 'on'
    at Object.static [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:75:8)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

When I go to the url '/stylesheets/style.css' I get this error:

```
Express
500 TypeError: Object #<SendStream> has no method 'on'

    at Object.static [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:75:8)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at /app/node_modules/stylus/lib/middleware.js:174:46
    at /app/node_modules/stylus/lib/middleware.js:208:20
```

Everything works fine locally.

here is the package.json

```
  {
    "name": "app-name",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
      "start": "node app"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "express": "3.0.0rc1",
       "jade": "*",
       "stylus": "*"
     }
   }
```

The app.js:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
 var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

The Procfile:

```
web: node app.js
```

If I keep refreshing, it crashes the app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to solve this by specifying the engine dependencies in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.0rc1",
    "jade": "*",
    "stylus": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.4",
    "npm": "1.1.41"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone clarify why specifying the node/npm engine versions solves the problem of static content request failing in Express?

I'm up-voting, cuz it worked for me, but this is a bit baffling?!

Comment: I'm assuming that it uses the wrong ones by default? ... someone with a little more knowledge than me should edit my answer to make it definitive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865214/how-do-i-serve-static-file-with-express-over-cloudfoundry?lq=1#comment15807086_11865687 Related issue?

Comment: This worked for me too.  Although, my versions of node and npm were newer than Heroku's, which caused a compilation error.  I just used the newest versions Heroku had (the versions are in the error message) and luckily it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer！
you got a wrong runtime of the application push to the cloud
you can do this

```
vmc push yourappname --runtime node08
```

i hope i can help you

Comment: when you push the app to the cloud ,
1st you shoud be select one of [node04 node06 node08],
and once you choose node04 and node06 ,the clound may remember it,
so you have no way to change you version of the Node without you push the app again

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and found that running the following command (via Heroku CLI) worked for me:

heroku config:add NODE_ENV=production

This was in conjunction with specifying the versions of Node and NPM as Silas mentioned.

(via http://quickleft.com/blog/getting-started-with-express-in-node)