# How do I serve static file with express over cloudfoundry?

Tags: express, cloud-foundry

How do I serve static files with express over cloudfoundry?
I was trying to use the following code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/www'));
```

but I am getting some bizarre exception when I am accessing the specific url:

```
TypeError: Object #<SendStream> has no method 'on'
    at Object.static [as handle] (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/FeedBack-0-c812c99aa3818946dd0bcf5538e2aecd/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:75:8)
    at next (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/FeedBack-0-c812c99aa3818946dd0bcf5538e2aecd/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/FeedBack-0-c812c99aa3818946dd0bcf5538e2aecd/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:31:5)
    at next (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/FeedBack-0-c812c99aa3818946dd0bcf5538e2aecd/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.query [as handle] (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/FeedBack-0-c812c99aa3818946dd0bcf5538e2aecd/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:44:5)
    at next (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/FeedBack-0-c812c99aa3818946dd0bcf5538e2aecd/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Function.handle (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/FeedBack-0-c812c99aa3818946dd0bcf5538e2aecd/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:198:3)
    at Server.app (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/FeedBack-0-c812c99aa3818946dd0bcf5538e2aecd/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:66:31)
    at Server.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1134:12)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'v got this wrong too,and i found the answer;
you can do this :

1st
   `vmc delete yourapp`

2nd `vmc push yourapp --runtime node08`

maybe you choose the wrong varsion of the Node runtime (node04,node06) at the 1st time you push the app to cloud ,and the server remember your choice.

Comment: As of Feb 13 you can now just do 
`$ vmc push yourapp --runtime node08` 
no reason to delete

Answer (score 2):

That should work, if you create a template express application it is configured to serve static assets from the ./public folder. Make sure your configuration is something like this;

```
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

If you would like, I can try and deploy your source myself and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: it doesn't work, I also add all my files to the public directory which is a directory under the directory where I use the vmc update command, right?

Comment: Did you create the app using the express console command or have you built it from scratch. If you could perhaps post the source as a Github gist or something, that would be of great help.

Comment: scratch, my application also serves dynamic content which works on cloudfoundry, both static and dynamic content works on my local machine

Comment: my code is huge, but a simple test app would be app that do just that app.js:app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); package file and a public folder that contains static html files

Comment: OK, all I am saying is that if you create an app using the standard express generated project static content works fine, so it has to be something about your app that CF doesn't quite like. I found someone else on SO that had the same issue with Heroku, maybe it's worth trying to apply the same fix? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789216/expresjs-not-loading-stylesheets-on-heroku-giving-500-error

Comment: what is the standard express generated project?

Comment: Take a look at "Getting Started" on the github readme - https://github.com/visionmedia/express. When you install the express node package globally, it installs a binary called express that you can use to generate a template project which has all the configuration for static content done for you. It may be worth generating one and comparing.